# How to highlight only part of an object when highlighting with B?

Tags: edit-mode

I'm following a tutorial on youtube called "Blender Beginner Tutorial - Part 3: Edit Mode" by *blender guru* and on the 18th minute he highlights the top half of his doughnut and or any part of it by holding *B* and highlighting over a selected area.

When I do it however it just automatically highlights the entire doughnut and not just a piece of it or where I highlight even if all I highlighted was a single edge or face. I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm new so I have much to learn.

Heres the link to the video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqeNA_4O0Qg

Comment: Pressing "B" activates a "box Select". You need to Left Click hold and drag the mouse to create a box around the area you would like to select. Pressing "A" will either select all or deselect all.

Comment: Do you maybe need to be in Edit Mode (Tab)?

Comment: It would be nice if you could link to the YouTube video to make it easier to see what you are following.